# Reading dynamic text from stop watch and inserting it back in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a stop watch stop when 5 divs have been clicked. Then i would like to insert this record time into a seperate div and display it to the person in question. The stop watch and clicking works fine but i can't seem to get the message to show.

```
$(".masterobject").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        if ($(".masterobject").length == $(".clicked").length){
        pause();
        var myrecordtime = document.GetElementById("yourtime");
        $("#success").show();
        $("#success").text('Congratulations! Your score is' + myrecordtime)
    }
    });
```

the masterobject class are the clicked divs. The pause() var works fine and after that is a mess. What is the correct way make sure the if statement runs all of this? Thanks in advance.
full code with the stop watch at http://jsfiddle.net/8qmyg/306/

Comment: I cannot find `.masterobject` anywhere in your code

Comment: `myrecordtime ` is a dom element not text. Code shown in question is different than code in demo

Comment: terribly sorry about that. i linked the wrong jsfiddle. this should be the correct one http://jsfiddle.net/8qmyg/306/

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting some more i solved it by changing the variable.

```
$(".masterobject").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        if ($(".masterobject").length == $(".clicked").length){
        pause();
        $("#success").show();
        var recordtime = $("#yourtime").text();
        $("#success").html("congratulations your time is" + recordtime)
    }
```

full code http://jsfiddle.net/8qmyg/307/